# Recursion Function return 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, recursion

My recursive function return undefined not list i don't know why what is the reason and i need solution to it  , i need help to solve this problem i coded it in another languages like c++ & java but it's not work in javascript and Thanks .

```
let arrCopy = []

 function solve(indx , cummlative,summation , lst){
  console.log(lst)
  if(indx == arrCopy.length){return 0 ;}
  if(cummlative == summation){return lst;}

  if((cummlative + arrCopy[indx]) <= summation){
    lst.push(arrCopy[indx])
    solve(indx + 1 , cummlative + arrCopy[indx] , summation , lst)
    lst.pop();
  }

     solve(indx + 1 , cummlative , summation , lst)
}
function ParallelSums(arr) {
  let summation = 0 ;
  for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; ++i){summation += arr[i];arrCopy.push(arr[i])}
  if(summation % 2 == 0){
    let valSummation = summation / 2 ;
    let val = solve(0 , 0,valSummation , [])
    console.log(val)
  }
  // code goes here
  return -1;

}

// keep this function call here
console.log(ParallelSums([1,4,2,3]));
```

Comment: If you want your function to return something, I would at least expect the word `return` to appear in the function

Comment: 1. You need `return` 2. You need to `return` the result of the recursive calls.

Comment: can you solve the problem to make output like that [ 1 , 4 ]  or [ 2 , 3 ]

Comment: Solve your own homework =) Specific questions and issues are good, 'fix this for me' is less good.

Comment: OK, after re-reading the question I have no idea what's it even asking. What is the problem you're solving? I have no idea what the end result is supposed to be or why.

Answer (score 0):

Either your base cases are not written correctly or you forgot to make a `return` at the end of the recursive function

```js
let arrCopy = []

 function solve(indx , cummlative,summation , lst){
  console.log(lst)
  if(indx == arrCopy.length){return 0 ;}
  if(cummlative == summation){return lst;}

  if((cummlative + arrCopy[indx]) <= summation){
    lst.push(arrCopy[indx])
    return solve(indx + 1 , cummlative + arrCopy[indx] , summation , lst)
    lst.pop();
  }

     return solve(indx + 1 , cummlative , summation , lst)
}
function ParallelSums(arr) {
  let summation = 0 ;
  for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; ++i){summation += arr[i];arrCopy.push(arr[i])}
  if(summation % 2 == 0){
    let valSummation = summation / 2 ;
    let val = solve(0 , 0,valSummation , [])
    console.log(val)
  }
  // code goes here
  return -1;

}

// keep this function call here
console.log(ParallelSums([1,4,2,3]));
```

Comment: base cases are correct , you made a wrong return

Comment: Specify what kind of behavior then do you expect?

Comment: can you solve the problem to make output like that [ 1 , 4 ] or [ 2 , 3 ]

Comment: Updated, let's check it